# Drag/Drop Functionality with div tags purely using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create a nested drag/drop functionality **using purely Javascript** (No Jquery or other plugins please).

The Idea is to have a several div tags as groups and having ability to drag that div tag/group on top of another div tag/group to create a sub group within itself(as a child of that group) max level of sub subs allowed is 4. To Illustrate what I am talking about please look at this Jquery Plugin NestedSortabled example, It defines exactly what I am looking for.

[NestedSortable Jquery Example](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/)

Another similar example: http://dbushell.com/2012/06/17/nestable-jquery-plugin/

I need to develop my code to function exactly like the example above, but using purely old school javascript only, please dont suggest any Jquery code.

Here is what I have currently working, However I am stuck right now and cant figure out how to get the sub grouping functionality to work. Please Help!!

**My working Demo:** http://jsbin.com/IzAfutI/1

**My working Demo + Code:** http://jsbin.com/IzAfutI/3/edit?html,css,js,output

**Edit:**

Let me example the code in more detail. StartDrag and StopDrag contain the main logic behind the functionality. Basically when user drags a div tag I am currently creating a container on top of or underneath a already existing div tag for the item that is to be dragged to be placed into, however when I use this same funcionality to create that container within another container(via creating sub group) I am getting an error. which means Maybe I am going at the problem the wrong way maybe my logic might be wrong or else something else wrong with the code.

HTML mark up of group div tag:

```
<div class="dragContainerUsed">
    <div id="a7b94a42-fb00-4011-bd5a-4b48e6e578c5" class="dragPanel">
        <input type="hidden" value="1|fa7989d7-1708-4a90-9bf6-c91f6cef6952" />
        <div onmousedown="startDrag(event, this.parentNode)" class="dragPanelHeader">
            <div style="margin-left:4px; margin-top:3px; float:left;">1 - Group 1<span id="gta7b94a42-fb00-4011-bd5a-4b48e6e578c5"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=\"dragSubContainerUnUsed\"></div>
</div>
<div class="dragContainerUnUsed"></div>
```

So what I want to happen is when user drags another div on top of the div dragSubContainerUnUsed it should be placed within that subContainer....

On start drag, I create a array to store all the containers and subContainers:

```
containers = new Array();

subContainers = new Array();

containers.push(dragTarget);
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className.toLowerCase() == "dragcontainerunused") {
        containers.push(divs[i]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (divs[i].className.toLowerCase() == "dragSubcontainerunused") {
        subContainers.push(divs[i]);
    }
}
```

and currently the part where I am stuck is in the functions `onDrag` and `stopDrag`, I dont know how to get the subContainers to work via to create the subgroups...

For Instance if I drag Group 3 on top of Group 2, I want group 3 to be a sub group of 2 Like this:
[image]

and I should be able to add max of 4 groups into each sub group, with max of 4 sub groups.
like this:
[image]

and finally there should only be a max of 4 levels of subgrouping
like this:
[image]

Please Help in anyway you can, if you can identify the problem than please tell me or if there needs to be a change in logic for my code tell me, Even if you can completely re-write/ create your own new code to make this application work would be very much appreciated. I have been trying to tackle this for a few days any and all help will be greatly accepted...

Comment: SO questions need to have code within the question, not on an external site.  What exactly is the problem?  This sounds like a simple case of `dragNode.parentNode.removeChild(dragNode); dropNode.appendChild(dragNode)`.

Comment: My Problem is I am trying to figure out the Logic/Code required for me to create sub grouping to work within my code, Currently you can drag/drop each individual groups, But I want to be able to drag a group onto/into each other alas creating sub groups within themselves with a max level of 4 subgroups

Comment: I think you might get more answers if you spot the problem by yourself and ask some more specific questions (and shorter maybe?)

Comment: well thats just it, the code I posted above using the subContainers is what i tired to do to create the sub grouping, but when i implement it breaks the existing way the drag/drop works which means I might not be approaching this the right way.

Comment: For instance, I am using div tags. while the examples in Jquery are using <li>. Sadly I dont have a strong understanding of Jquery just quiet yet, so I am hoping someone can read that Jquery code in those examples and help me with my native javascript form of those examples.

Comment: (1) just use jquery, its not that hard and well worth it (2) what you want is to create a `<ul>` after each div and add the `<div>`s dragged to it as `<li>`s

Comment: i will be honest asking how to do this w/o jquery, is asking "how do i create manipulable 3d images in plain html - i dont know css/js/jquery or java/flash".

Comment: jQueryUI is open source. Have you tried looking at the code behind their drag and drop functionality (draggable control)?

Comment: @ginman yes, I have and I even tried to convert that Jquery into native javascript but I do not have a strong knowledge of Jquery. I can post the Jquery code for what exactly I am looking for, if you want so maybe someone can assit me in converting it into native javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been working on this, completed it couple of months ago. but forgot about this post. so i decided to post the complete solution for anyone else that might be looking for a answer to this enjoy.

The entire code is too long to post it in here, but here is the link to the code:
[Drag/Drop Functionality with Div Tags](http://jsbin.com/aTUHULu/1/edit)

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/aTUHULu/1

Answer (score 2):

Check This code

```
function allowDrop(ev){

ev.preventDefault();

}

function drag(ev)
{

ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);


}

function drop(ev) 
{

ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


}


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>"

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to divide the drop rectangle into 4 areas , if you drop it in the first one it will be on level 1 and if you drop it on the next 40px lets say it will be considered level 2 and hence

Answer (score -1):

I would post the code as well if you want but I think the approach itself would work if you try and implement it. Here is the approach

Instead of div, add the item as a listitem

. This would auto intend the control and it would be very easy for you to parse it at the end. What you need to do here is that onDrop, take the text (and other properties) from the  div, create a li and add the div in that li. This would enable your code to redrag and drop the div further. Note - remember to remove the li (or ul according to the parent of div) when drag ends.

Comment: I tired to do a similar approach before, but maybe my knowledge of this whole DOM manipulation is a bit limited as i am beginner. Is it possible for you to make that change within my code (http://jsbin.com/IzAfutI/3/edit) or maybe post a working code for your solution. Thank you very much for your help dear sir!!

Comment: have you had the chance to view my comment above, can you please post the code as well. I am looking for any help at this point....

Comment: SO is not a help desk

Comment: I believe I added enough context for you to modify the code. Didnt understand down vote!!! SO is for answer not spoon feeding